# Booting into recovery from terminal

Tags: cyanogenmod, recovery-mode, terminal

How can I boot into the recovery from terminal? I'm using LG p970/CM10/cwm5

Comment: Do you mean from the terminal on your desktop (using `adb`) or from a shell on the Android device itself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `reboot recovery`, though it doesn't work on all devices. You might also need root for this, so first try `su`.

Comment: `su root`? Simply `su` should do :)

Comment: CM12 and perhaps CM11 too has ADB wireless option under Developer settings, and combined with "adb connect" you can boot into Recovery mode without needing `su`. But having CM already means you'll be having root access too, so how is this comment useful? -- Well for those running stock CyanogenOS. :) // But that's just command-line way, Developer options also has Advanced boot options, so GUI will provide "reboot to recovery" option as well. -- [Warren T. Voider](http://android.stackexchange.com/users/116816/warren-t-voider) came up with this part.

Answer (score 0):

It may not work if you have not-always-compatibile busybox reboot symlink in a PATH that is more privileged than /system/bin (or /system/bin toolbox symlink has been overwritten), it may lie in /sbin if using custom kernel with bb included for example. If so, try:
"toolbox reboot recovery" (jb)
"/system/bin/reboot recovery" (kk - however which one will work my be also dependent from the manufacturer...)

Answer (score 0):

If you are running CM11 or CM12 you can simply go to Settings> About Phone> and tap Build Number 7-10 times to unlock Dev Options. Once unlocked you can go to Setting > Developer Options and select Advanced Reboot, this will add a "Reboot to Recovery" option to your reboot menu. Easiest method I have found to get unto recovery without installing a 3rd party app or using a terminal command if your phone doesn't want to accept a multi button sequence. Also note that in Cyanogenmod 12 you have to enable the Superuser root access in the Dev options first I believe.

Comment: OP plainly wrote: *"I'm using LG p970/CM10/cwm5"* -- CM10.

Comment: I added a [comment](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/50366/booting-into-recovery-from-terminal/115274#comment142929_50369) mentioning you and the gist of your answer on the accepted answer, in case your answer is removed for some reason. :)

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't answer the question for a quite different reason: OP asks how to do that ***from terminal*** – which your post does not cover at all.